# Is there any API documentation available for Perfecto Selenium and appium plugins

Tags: perfecto

Is there any API documentation available for Perfecto Selenium and appium plugins
as we have API for android with Google  https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Comment: You can check http://developers.perfectomobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

Saravan,

Perfecto extend Appium and Selenium in the following way:
- All Appium & Selenium API should be supported by Perfecto - It should work in the same way that it works with standard Selenium remote web driver or Appium. 
- The only thing you should do in order to run your test on Perfecto cloud is to change the driver to run on Perfecto cloud.
- Perfecto extend and add additional capabilities leveraging standard executescript function - You can read more here : https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/1010994-perfecto-proprietary-features-commands
- The way that Appium & selenium support was designed is that the server is on Perfecto cloud which provide the ability to support new OS versions and devices once they are released (including beta versions).

Just to be fair - I work at Perfecto.